# Относительное позиционирование элементов одного уровня

Tags: css

Есть несколько одинаковых блоков, нужно чтобы один заехал на другой, но со смещением влево вниз-вниз. То есть если убрать это смещение, то элементы будут стопкой один на другом. 
На скрине схематичный пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал написать следующий код, но элементы сместились как мне надо только по горизонтали, мне же нужно чтобы по вертикали отступ от верха считался от предыдущего элемента. Понятно что можно напистаь длинный css или сократить это javascriptом, но может быть есть универсальный способ на css?

```css
.item-doc {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 180px;
  background: rgba(94, 158, 21, 0.67);
  margin-left: -170px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.item-doc:first-child {
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-doc"></div>
<div class="item-doc"></div>
<div class="item-doc"></div>
<div class="item-doc"></div>
<div class="item-doc"></div>
<div class="item-doc"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.item-doc {
 position: relative;
 width: 150px;
 height: 180px;
 background: rgba(94, 158, 21, 0.67);
 margin-left: 170px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.item-doc > .item-doc {
 position: absolute;
 left: -10px;
 top: 10px;
 margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-doc">
 <div class="item-doc">
  <div class="item-doc">
   <div class="item-doc"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для этого уже лучше применять препроцессоры.

Например scss:

```
.item-doc {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 180px;
  background: rgba(94, 158, 21, 0.67);  
  margin-top: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

@for $i from 0 through 10 {
  .item-doc:nth-child(#{$i+1}){
    left: 200px - $i*200;
    top: $i*50px;
  }
}
```

Конвертирует в:

```
.item-doc:nth-child(1) {
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
}

.item-doc:nth-child(2) {
  left: 0px;
  top: 50px;
}

.item-doc:nth-child(3) {
  left: -200px;
  top: 100px;
}

.item-doc:nth-child(4) {
  left: -400px;
  top: 150px;
}

.item-doc:nth-child(5) {
  left: -600px;
  top: 200px;
}
...
```

[Пример на JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cuqusoy/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Ну тогда уж лучше в js прописать))) тем более сам файл подключен, просто не хотел лишний раз браузер нагружать

Comment: Не лучше! Не нужно пихать js лишь бы где.

Comment: Ровно так же как подключать линие файлы если можно использовать существующие

Comment: О каких лишних файлах Вы говорите?!

Comment: Все понял, спасибо)

Comment: Который отлично компилируется в css

Comment: в общем никогда с никогда не работал с препроцессорами, мне нужно будет подключать дополнительные файлы или библиотеки, если нет, то кто ведет расчеты, если не движок браузера, А если он, то скорее всего не все браузер будут поддерживать.

Comment: Если не хотите использовать дополнительного чего-то типа gulp сборщика, то есть же online компиляторы). 
Но если у Вас такой случай единичный, то и ручками можно прописать, но на css, а то 21-й век, уже разработчики html/css столько плюшек всяких придумали, а некоторые до сих пор js-ом верстку выравнивают.

Comment: И все, естественно, в ваших руках, я же только предложила пример, а не обязательно решение)) Выбирать Вам!